# File uploading to Synology NAS Server fails in MAC OS

Tags: synology, nas

I currently purchased Synology's ds220+ model and am using it as a NAS Server.

The line is connected to the LAN port of the router to which the WAN line is plugged, and the end is connected to the NAS.

In this situation, I wanted to set up a NAS server to be used externally, not on a local network.

So I even set up WebDAV Server, DDNS, and port forwarding on the router.

To test this, I created a NAS server directory through RaiDrive in a Windows environment.

From the created directory, I tried to upload files to a folder with read/write permission and confirmed that it was working normally.

However, the problem occurred in MacOS.

In Finder, a server folder was created through the "Connect to Server" option, and a file upload was attempted, but an error such as the attached picture occurred in all types of files.

Could you tell me if there is a problem with the way MAC creates the server folder?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Idea: Your OS doesn't support SMB:
   Download an FTP or SMB client. (FTP: E.g.: Filezilla)
2. Idea: A friewall is blocking it:
   Check your anti-virus-program
3. Other Problem:
   Use an USB Stick & NAS USB Copy
   or upload it via DSM File Manager

   0. Open NAS IP-adress via Safari/Firefox/Chrome
   1. Log In
   2. Open File Station / File Manager
   3. Search folder
   4. Click [Upload]
   5. Choose the file from your PC
   6. Finised